# How to integrate jasper and gwt?

Tags: java, gwt

I am using gwt. How integrate jasper with gwt to generate excel report? What are the steps to integrate? Mine is a web application which has gwt, spring, hibernate and maven. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are the steps I have used in my application.

1) Download the ireport software from [here](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport)

2) Generate/design a **.jrxml** file based on your application requirement

3) copy that designed **.jrxml** file to your source resources directory

4) Add the [jasper reports maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jasperreports-maven-plugin/) to your pom.xml. Using this plugin you can compile **.jrxml** file to **.jasper** file.

5) Add the jasper report jar dependency to your application and generate the report to some directory. By reading jasper report documents you can achieve this step.

6)Provide a link to download that file in UI.

Depends on your application requirements above steps may change.

Answer (score 0):

For integrating with gwt you just need:

> Window.open("yourUrlToServlet","_blank","");

Your excel report generating logic should be in your servlet(server-side), tell the browser where to 
download/open the file once its generated.

Comment: hi jamshid,thanks for ur reply. I achieved everything using poi. I need to use now jasper. What r the steps to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: There is no additional configuration, and there is no dependency with gwt you just make a link(servlet) which responsible for generating an excel file, this is how you achieved with poi. see this http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-reporting-part-2 but in server side you should add the file into your response.

Answer (score 0):

I use a GWT RPC to an AppEngine hosted servlet that restfully calls a JasperReports server that is also hosted on the same Google Cloud Project as the Appengine. JasperReports REST v2 makes is really easy to call a report in many formats (including Excel)

http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide/v56/rest-web-services-overview