# Jasper reports Server and GWT integration

Tags: gwt

I ve installed Jasper Reports Server and i want to develop a GWT application to call the jasper server web services as : Login , Running a report in the server, listing reports, View User .... I 've implemented web services in java through the Jasper Soft web services guide for example for authentitcation :

```
public static void connect(String URL,HttpClient httpclient)
{
    serverURL = URL;
    //report path               

                    HttpClient client = httpclient;

                    // Setting Login URL in a POST method
                    String loginURL = serverURL+"rest/login";

                    PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod(loginURL);

                    // Set authentication parameters
                    postMethod.addParameter("j_username", "jasperadmin");
                    postMethod.addParameter("j_password", "jasperadmin");
                    int statusCodeL;
                    try {
                        statusCodeL=client.executeMethod(postMethod);

                        if (statusCodeL != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                            System.out.println("Login failed: " + postMethod.getStatusLine());
                            return;
                        }
                    }catch (HttpException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

But i can t explore those web services when developing with GWT framework Which is no compatible with HTTPClient, even when using the Request Builder the authentication failed.

My question is HOW TO INTEGRATE JASPER REPORTS SERVER INTO GWT APPLICATION ?

Comment: Please see my answer at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163043/how-to-integrate-jasper-and-gwt

Answer (score 0):

I also had to implement the Jasper Report integration at my company. And yes, I also had difficulties. We ended up only using the [Jasper Report Library](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library) to generate our report and we did the rest ourselves (listing reports, storing generated reports, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use GWT. In the HttpServlet, have that call the Jasper APIs. Then the HttpServlet can return the results of the Jasper call to GWT. I put a comment that links to where the answer is.